# Cannot create VHost on RabbitMQ Management HTTP API

Tags: rabbitmq

I've done some research as to how to create a vHost from the HTTP API on RabbitMQ. I am brand new to RabbitMQ so I just need some basic guidance. I've seen to add a vhost you go to the admin page and there is an option for virtual hosts. However, when I am in mine, I do not have said option. I don't know if there is something else I need to install or enable but I can't seem to find anyone else with this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the right permissions to create a vhost. Check your permissions and make sure you are logged in with a user that has the administrator tag according to this: [https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#:~:text=and%20credential%20management.-,Tag,-Capabilities](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#:%7E:text=and%20credential%20management.-,Tag,-Capabilities)

The HTTP API documentation has an example on how to create a vhost:
$ curl -i -u USER:PASSWORD -H "content-type:application/json" 
-XPUT http://localhost:15672/api/vhosts/foo

Comment: Thank you! That page led me to the Vhost page where I was able to at least use the curl command to add a Vhost through the terminal.